# Azure Policy extraction using PowerShell on Subscription

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-policy

I am trying to extract assigned policy name on subscription level using powershell cmd but unable to get it.
Suggestion please

Using Below CMDlet
Get-AzPolicyAssignment -Scope "/subscriptions/gef21de3e19-5df1-481xxej842"

Comment: Command is right. Have you selected the corresponding subscription before? I.E. if you run `(Get-AzContext).Subscription.Id` are you getting the subscription Id that you are using in your `Get-AzPolicyAssignment` command?

Answer (score 0):

Azure command looks correct.

You can try in Windows PowerShell ISE instead of Azure PowerShell.
You can install Azure modules from NuGet provider as shown below:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope AllUsers -Repository PSGallery -Force -AllowClobber
```

---

You can try this command that worked for me:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "SubscriptionId here"
$PolicySet = Get-AzPolicySetDefinition
Get-AzPolicyAssignment -Scope "/Subscriptions/SubscriptionId here"
```

[image]

**Note**: Two conditions to check:

1. You need to connect to AZ account before you are trying to get policy assignments by using the command.
2. You need to check whether the value is stored in the particular object. ( Eg: $policyset)